# Creating a simple report in Omniture

Tags: report, adobe-analytics

I have a simple site for which I want to create a report in Omniture.

I just have two links which I want to record that how many times they are clicked. Basically something like a completely novice report.

Any idea, how I can start it and how I can implement it?

I have an Omniture account.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do click tracking pretty simply with a link like this

```
<a href="#" onclick="s.tl(this,'o','INSERT LINK NAME',null)">
```

Those values you insert in the link name will show up under Site Content >> Links >> Custom Links

Search the help section for link tracking or read this https://microsite.omniture.com/t2/help/en_US/sc/implement/index.html#Manual_Link_Tracking_Using_Custom_Link_Code

Comment: Thanks a lot Brett. Any chance I can find a detailed tutorial on Omniture?

Comment: I don't know of any tutorials but the implementation guide can get you started. Also, the videos in the help section are now free and there is good stuff in there as well.

Comment: Do you know of a way to get this data from the API? I have set the metric to 'Instances' and tried various elements with no luck

Answer (score 0):

I never knew it'd be so hard to find a simple tutorial for SiteCatalyst (Omniture). One of the most to-the-point is here.

http://webanalyticsland.com/sitecatalyst-implementation/implement-sitecatalyst-in-5-minutes

Please let me know if you found something better.

Thanks.

Comment: Well to be fair, this is an enterprise level analytics solution. It doesn't cater to average Joe like Google Analytics. You are expected to be a professional level coder. Omniture (Adobe) does offer training courses and certifications for it.

Comment: Every professional level coder has to go through an Amateur level. (I think).

Comment: Well in general, yes.  What I'm saying though is that Omniture tracking is not really for Amateur level coders. It's like wanting to run before you've even learned to walk.

Answer (score 0):

While searching for the tutorials, the only one which is bit helpful (although old) is:

http://tv.adobe.com/watch/learn-adobe-digital-marketing/sitecatalyst-interface-part-one/